# Intellij tests pass, mvn test fails

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit

## Main problem

I am working on a spring-boot application.
I have test, with `@autowired`serivces. All tests pass when I run them in IntelliJ. However, when I run `mvn test`from command line, nullpointer-exceptions are thrown.

Any help is greatly appreaciated!

Olav

## Example of test

```java
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class,
        webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.NONE)
public class CategoryServiceTest extends ServiceTestBase {

    @Autowired
    private CategoryService categoryService;


    @Test
    public void testNoCategory() {
        List<Category> categories = categoryService.getAllCategories(false);
        assertEquals(0, categories.size());
    }
    //...
}
```

### Application class

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

## Output in command line (one for every test using a service)

```
org.olaven.quizgame.services.QuizServiceTest.testQuizWithoutSubCategoryFails()  Time elapsed: 0 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.olaven.quizgame.services.QuizServiceTest.testQuizWithoutSubCategoryFails(QuizServiceTest.java:219)
```

## QuizServiceTest.java line 217-220

```java
Long categoryId = categoryService.createCategory(getRandomString(10));
Long subCategoryId = categoryService.createSubCategory(categoryId, getRandomString(10));
Long quizId = quizService.createQuiz(subCategoryId, getRandomString(10), "1", "2", "3", "4", 0);
```

## POM file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>olaven</groupId>
    <artifactId>quizgame</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <version.springboot>2.1.3.RELEASE</version.springboot>
        <version.junit>5.0.2</version.junit>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${version.springboot}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${version.springboot}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
            <version>${version.springboot}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>${version.springboot}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>${version.springboot}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${version.junit}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>




        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.198</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <finalName>quizgame</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${version.springboot}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <finalName>quizgame</finalName>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <classifier>exec</classifier>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Have you defined `test` parameter as outlined [here](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/single-test.html)?

Comment: I tried to run `mvn surefire:test -Dtest=CategoryServiceTest`and `mvn -Dtest=QuizServiceTest test`. Thanks for the advice, but unfortunately neither worked.

Comment: Gotcha.  Could you paste your pom.xml as part of your question?

Comment: Updated now :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try to add newer `maven-surefire-plugin` version into your pom.xml:

```
<build>
     <plugins>
         ....
         <plugin>
             <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
             <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
             <version>2.22.0</version>
         </plugin>
         ....
     </plugins>
 </build>
```

Comment: Could you also add a short explanation for your answer ?

Comment: @Gautam Junit 4 tests are supported by maven surefire plugin since 2.22 version. See https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-build-maven and https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-1330