# mvn test -Premote fails but succeeds on IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, wildfly

Running test in IDEA succeeds but when I try `mvn clean test -Premote` (or -Plocal) from command line fails with this exception:

```
org.jboss.arquillian.container.spi.client.container.DeploymentException: Cannot deploy: 4e9ef195-5038-410c-965a-872aa5473cde.war
        at org.jboss.as.arquillian.container.ArchiveDeployer.createException(ArchiveDeployer.java:214)
        at org.jboss.as.arquillian.container.ArchiveDeployer.deployInternal(ArchiveDeployer.java:179)
        at org.jboss.as.arquillian.container.ArchiveDeployer.deployInternal(ArchiveDeployer.java:162)
        at org.jboss.as.arquillian.container.ArchiveDeployer.deploy(ArchiveDeployer.java:91)
        at org.jboss.as.arquillian.container.CommonDeployableContainer.deploy(CommonDeployableContainer.java:244)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController$3.call(ContainerDeployController.java:151)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController$3.call(ContainerDeployController.java:118)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController.executeOperation(ContainerDeployController.java:239)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController.deploy(ContainerDeployController.java:118)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:86)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:103)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:90)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.createDeploymentContext(ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.java:71)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:86)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:95)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.createContainerContext(ContainerDeploymentContextHandler.java:54)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:86)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:95)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.DeploymentExceptionHandler.verifyExpectedExceptionDuringDeploy(DeploymentExceptionHandler.java:47)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:86)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:95)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:133)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:105)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:62)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController$1.perform(ContainerDeployController.java:92)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController$1.perform(ContainerDeployController.java:77)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController.forEachDeployment(ContainerDeployController.java:232)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController.forEachManagedDeployment(ContainerDeployController.java:212)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerDeployController.deployManaged(ContainerDeployController.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:86)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:103)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:90)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:133)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:105)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:62)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.ContainerEventController.execute(ContainerEventController.java:96)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:86)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:103)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:90)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createClassContext(TestContextHandler.java:83)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:86)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:95)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createSuiteContext(TestContextHandler.java:69)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:86)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:95)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:133)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:105)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.beforeClass(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:89)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$2.evaluate(Arquillian.java:163)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.multiExecute(Arquillian.java:350)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.access$200(Arquillian.java:54)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$3.evaluate(Arquillian.java:177)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
        at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.run(Arquillian.java:115)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
        Suppressed: java.net.ConnectException: WFLYPRT0053: Could not connect to remote+http://127.0.0.1:9990. The connection failed
                at org.jboss.as.protocol.ProtocolConnectionUtils.connectSync(ProtocolConnectionUtils.java:128)
                at org.jboss.as.protocol.ProtocolConnectionManager$EstablishingConnection.connect(ProtocolConnectionManager.java:259)
                at org.jboss.as.protocol.ProtocolConnectionManager.connect(ProtocolConnectionManager.java:70)
                at org.jboss.as.protocol.mgmt.ManagementClientChannelStrategy$Establishing.getChannel(ManagementClientChannelStrategy.java:167)
                at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.RemotingModelControllerClient.getOrCreateChannel(RemotingModelControllerClient.java:132)
                at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.RemotingModelControllerClient$2.getChannel(RemotingModelControllerClient.java:85)
                at org.jboss.as.protocol.mgmt.ManagementChannelHandler.executeRequest(ManagementChannelHandler.java:135)
                at org.jboss.as.protocol.mgmt.ManagementChannelHandler.executeRequest(ManagementChannelHandler.java:110)
                at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.AbstractModelControllerClient.executeRequest(AbstractModelControllerClient.java:263)
                at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.AbstractModelControllerClient.execute(AbstractModelControllerClient.java:168)
                at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.AbstractModelControllerClient.executeForResult(AbstractModelControllerClient.java:147)
                at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.AbstractModelControllerClient.execute(AbstractModelControllerClient.java:75)
                at org.jboss.as.controller.client.helpers.DelegatingModelControllerClient.execute(DelegatingModelControllerClient.java:63)
                at org.wildfly.plugin.core.ServerHelper.isDomainServer(ServerHelper.java:114)
                at org.wildfly.plugin.core.DefaultDeploymentManager$LazyDomainCheck.get(DefaultDeploymentManager.java:500)
                at org.wildfly.plugin.core.DefaultDeploymentManager.isDomain(DefaultDeploymentManager.java:464)
                at org.wildfly.plugin.core.DefaultDeploymentManager.validateDeployment(DefaultDeploymentManager.java:424)
                at org.wildfly.plugin.core.DefaultDeploymentManager.deploy(DefaultDeploymentManager.java:63)
                at org.jboss.as.arquillian.container.ArchiveDeployer.deployInternal(ArchiveDeployer.java:177)
                ... 96 more
        Caused by: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: Authentication failed: all available authentication mechanisms failed:
   JBOSS-LOCAL-USER: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: ELY05128: Failed to read challenge file [Caused by java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/wildfly/standalone/tmp/auth/local7171406162165043352.challenge (Permission denied)]
                at org.jboss.remoting3.remote.ClientConnectionOpenListener.allMechanismsFailed(ClientConnectionOpenListener.java:109)
                at org.jboss.remoting3.remote.ClientConnectionOpenListener$Capabilities.handleEvent(ClientConnectionOpenListener.java:445)
                at org.jboss.remoting3.remote.ClientConnectionOpenListener$Capabilities.handleEvent(ClientConnectionOpenListener.java:244)
                at org.xnio.ChannelListeners.invokeChannelListener(ChannelListeners.java:92)
                at org.xnio.conduits.ReadReadyHandler$ChannelListenerHandler.readReady(ReadReadyHandler.java:66)
                at org.xnio.nio.NioSocketConduit.handleReady(NioSocketConduit.java:89)
                at org.xnio.nio.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:591)
                at ...asynchronous invocation...(Unknown Source)
                at org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl.connect(EndpointImpl.java:599)
                at org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl.connect(EndpointImpl.java:561)
                at org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl.connect(EndpointImpl.java:549)
                at org.jboss.as.protocol.ProtocolConnectionUtils.connect(ProtocolConnectionUtils.java:204)
                at org.jboss.as.protocol.ProtocolConnectionUtils.connectSync(ProtocolConnectionUtils.java:120)
                ... 114 more
                Suppressed: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: ELY05128: Failed to read challenge file [Caused by java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/wildfly/standalone/tmp/auth/local7171406162165043352.challenge (Permission denied)]
                        at org.wildfly.security.sasl.localuser.LocalUserClient.evaluateMessage(LocalUserClient.java:108)
                        at org.wildfly.security.sasl.util.AbstractSaslParticipant.evaluateMessage(AbstractSaslParticipant.java:219)
                        at org.wildfly.security.sasl.util.AbstractSaslClient.evaluateChallenge(AbstractSaslClient.java:98)
                        at org.wildfly.security.sasl.util.AbstractDelegatingSaslClient.evaluateChallenge(AbstractDelegatingSaslClient.java:54)
                        at org.wildfly.security.sasl.util.PrivilegedSaslClient.lambda$evaluateChallenge$0(PrivilegedSaslClient.java:55)
                        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
                        at org.wildfly.security.sasl.util.PrivilegedSaslClient.evaluateChallenge(PrivilegedSaslClient.java:55)
                        at org.jboss.remoting3.remote.ClientConnectionOpenListener$Authentication.lambda$handleEvent$0(ClientConnectionOpenListener.java:649)
                        at org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl$TrackingExecutor.lambda$execute$0(EndpointImpl.java:991)
                        at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
                        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
                        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
                        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
                        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
                Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/wildfly/standalone/tmp/auth/local7171406162165043352.challenge (Permission denied)
                        at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
                        at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:219)
                        at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:157)
                        at org.wildfly.security.sasl.localuser.LocalUserClient.evaluateMessage(LocalUserClient.java:94)
                        ... 13 more
        [CIRCULAR REFERENCE:javax.security.sasl.SaslException: Authentication failed: all available authentication mechanisms failed:
   JBOSS-LOCAL-USER: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: ELY05128: Failed to read challenge file [Caused by java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/wildfly/standalone/tmp/auth/local7171406162165043352.challenge (Permission denied)]]
```

It's weird because the host is not 127.0.0.1:9990 but X.Y.Z.Q:9990.
Here's my Arquillian.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<arquillian xmlns="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian
    http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian/arquillian_1_0.xsd">

    <defaultProtocol type="Servlet 3.0" />

    <container qualifier="remote">
        <!-- Arquillian will deploy to this WildFly server. -->
        <configuration>
            <property name="managementAddress">${host}</property>
            <property name="managementPort">${port}</property>
            <!-- If deploying to a remote server, you have to specify username/password here -->
            <property name="username">${login}</property>
            <property name="password">${password}</property>
        </configuration>
    </container>

    <extension qualifier="webdriver">
        <property name="browser">${browser}</property>
    </extension>
</arquillian>
```

My Pom.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
   ...
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <version.wildfly.maven.plugin>2.0.0.Final</version.wildfly.maven.plugin>
        <version.jboss.bom>19.0.0.Final</version.jboss.bom>

        <version.compiler.plugin>3.8.1</version.compiler.plugin>
        <version.surefire.plugin>2.22.1</version.surefire.plugin>
        <version.failsafe.plugin>2.22.1</version.failsafe.plugin>
        <version.war.plugin>3.2.2</version.war.plugin>

        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>

        <browser>chrome</browser>
    </properties>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.bom</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-jakartaee8-with-tools</artifactId>
                <version>${version.jboss.bom}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
                <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.1.Final</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.enterprise.cdi-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-jsf-api_2.3_spec</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-jaxrs-api_2.1_spec</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-servlet-api_4.0_spec</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-ejb-api_3.2_spec</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.graphene</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphene-webdriver</artifactId>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Needed for proper browser tests-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>22.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.protocol</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-protocol-servlet</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </testResource>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                <targetPath>${project.basedir}/src/test/webapp/</targetPath>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${version.war.plugin}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    <archive>
                        <manifestFile>src/main/resources/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${version.wildfly.maven.plugin}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <hostname>${wildfly-hostname}</hostname>
                    <port>${wildfly-port}</port>
                    <username>${wildfly-username}</username>
                    <password>${wildfly-password}</password>
                    <jboss-home>${path-to-server}</jboss-home>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <filesets>
                        <fileset>
                            <directory>src/test/webapp</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*</include>
                            </includes>
                            <followSymlinks>false</followSymlinks>
                        </fileset>
                    </filesets>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${version.compiler.plugin}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
                    <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>local</id>
            <properties>
                <host>${wildfly-hostname}</host>
                <port>${wildfly-port}</port>
                <login>${wildfly-username}</login>
                <password>${wildfly-password}</password>
                <public-host>${wildfly-public-hostname}</public-host>
                <public-port>${wildfly-public-port}</public-port>
            </properties>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.wildfly.arquillian</groupId>
                    <artifactId>wildfly-arquillian-container-remote</artifactId>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${version.failsafe.plugin}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>integration-test</goal>
                                    <goal>verify</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <!-- Configuration for Arquillian: -->
                            <systemPropertyVariables>
                                <!-- Defines the container qualifier in "arquillian.xml" -->
                                <arquillian.launch>remote</arquillian.launch>
                            </systemPropertyVariables>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>remote</id>
            <properties>
                <host>${wildfly-hostname}</host>
                <port>${wildfly-port}</port>
                <login>${wildfly-username}</login>
                <password>${wildfly-password}</password>
                <public-host>${wildfly-public-hostname}</public-host>
                <public-port>${wildfly-public-port}</public-port>
            </properties>
            <activation>
            </activation>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.wildfly.arquillian</groupId>
                    <artifactId>wildfly-arquillian-container-remote</artifactId>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${version.failsafe.plugin}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>integration-test</goal>
                                    <goal>verify</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <!-- Configuration for Arquillian: -->
                            <systemPropertyVariables>
                                <!-- Defines the container qualifier in "arquillian.xml" -->
                                <arquillian.launch>remote</arquillian.launch>
                            </systemPropertyVariables>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

The `${wildfly-hostname}` is defined in maven's settings.xml file and the value is not 127.0.0.1. (as in the error message at WFLYPRT0053). IDEA uses the same settings.xml and test runs properly. Why I got this error running test from command line (using mvn test)?
I checked *[mvn test fails but running the test from IntelliJ IDEA pass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58935046/mvn-test-fails-but-running-the-test-from-intellij-idea-pass)* and *[Intellij tests pass, mvn test fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55082040/intellij-tests-pass-mvn-test-fails)* without result.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Is the server running?

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins: yes, it's running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arquillian uses common container's values by default. In stack trace there is a line

`JBOSS-LOCAL-USER: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: ELY05128: Failed to read challenge file [Caused by java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/wildfly/standalone/tmp/auth/local7171406162165043352.challenge (Permission denied)]`

which is a default local server path and wants to connect to local address:

`java.net.ConnectException: WFLYPRT0053: Could not connect to remote+http://127.0.0.1:9990. The connection failed`

The default values are declared in **org.jboss.as.arquillian.container.CommonContainerConfiguration**. If you want to use wildfly-remote-container you **must** set default container in arquillian.xml regardless on number of container settings:

```
<container qualifier="remote" default="true">
        <!-- Arquillian will deploy to this WildFly server. -->
        <configuration>
            <property name="managementAddress">${host}</property>
            <property name="managementPort">${port}</property>
            <!-- If deploying to a remote server, you have to specify username/password here -->
            <property name="username">${login}</property>
            <property name="password">${password}</property>
        </configuration>
    </container>
```

In this case it will use server properties given in pom.xml's profile settings.